# Why this program is giving seg fault?

Tags: c, pointers

This is my program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *n;
    int var;
    scanf("%d",n);
    printf("%d",*n);

}
```

as `scanf` stores the value at specified address I am giving the address .Then I am trying to print value at address but its giving segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allocate memory for pointers like this:

```
int* n = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I need to alocate memory first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858

Answer (score 2):

It's because a block of memory has not been allocated to contain the integer value referenced by the variable `n`. You have only initialized a pointer to the memory block, not the memory block itself.

If you instead do the following, the code will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

Comment: +1 for being simpler and more obvious than `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

var `n` is pointer, and you didn't malloc memory for it.